# Assalamualaikum my question is is it halal for a muslimah to race say in formula racing cars when she she has a sponsor and she wears modestly?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I need to know if it's ok to play if you have a sponsor and if you play abiding by islamic rules and you wear modestly ..

Answer (score 1):

Racing is not prohibited in Islam. And what you mean by wear modestly? As long as you follow the hijab rules of covering your body and the dress is not tight it is good to go. And make sure the sponsorship is not about Haram, like Alcohol, Smoking, betting, etc.

Islam's Hijab is not a dress but a dress code, so follow the dress code. Some muslim volleyball players play like this [Picture](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs40/f/2009/024/c/5/muslim_volleyball_player_by_Jesesita.jpg). This is hijab dress code not the black dress women wear.

Edit:

The picture I used as a reference focuses on the woman numbered 22 who is in hijab, not others who is in black shorts.

Comment: I already said the dress should not be tight. I put the picture as a rough reference only.

Answer (score 0):

No, she shouldn't do that unless she needs to. Women are not permitted to leave their home except in need.

"And stay in your homes and do not expose your beauty the way they used to expose in the times of ignorance..." - Quran 33:33

Ibn Kathir (RH) states in his tafseer of this verse that this command is only to curb leaving the home “without any need, and from amongst the needs which are valid according to the Sacred Law is praying in the mosque, education, keeping up ties with family, etc, while observing its conditions.”

The line: “while observing its conditions” means:

1. Modest dress and behavior,
2. A productive and genuine purpose, and
3. Avoiding people and places where sin are observed.

Prophet Muhammad PBUH said: "O women! You have been allowed by Allah to go out for your needs." [Sahih Bukhari 5237]

Prophet Muhammad PBUH said: "The woman is 'awrah, when she goes out, Shaitan seeks to tempt her. She is never closer to Allah than when she's in her home." [At-Tabarani's Al-Mu'jam al-Awsat 2890, Ibn Hibbaan 5599, Ibn Khuzaymah 1591]

Comment: What if her husband, father or brother accompany her, then is she not allowed? What is the proper reason? What about doing a business with her husband or going to a tournament with her father?

Comment: Even if her husband or father permits or accompany her, she shouldn't go out if there's no need. Prophet's words precedes the words of any other man, "O women! You have been allowed by Allah to go out for your needs." If she needs to support her husband in business, she could go out. If there's no need, then she can support him from home. If she needs to take part in a tournament, then she can. 'Need' is the yardstick.

Comment: If she can participate in tournament, then what is the problem?

Comment: Does she needs to participate in the tournament? If yes, she can. If not, she shouldn't. Even if she needs but can't fulfil the conditions of hijab, then she shouldn't participate. Islam is more important than tournament. Allah will never ask whether she participated in tournament or not. Prophet Muhammad PBUH said: "Love for dunya is the root of all evil." (Bayhaqi)

Comment: the question is about race and hijab, and you said it is ok to race and the hijab part was answered, then why are you still commenting about it. Since you yourself said that a woman can race if she maintains hijab then it is answered right? And yes she needs to race that's why the question.

Comment: Read properly. I said she can take part in the tournament if she NEEDS to. Islam forbids women to go out without a NEED as it is protection. Refer to my answer above. If she wants to race, she can't. If she needs to race, she can. But first, does she need to race? She has to answer whether it's a need or a want. Not you or me.

Comment: What is your definition of NEED? and what is the definition of NEED in ISLAM? Does Islam forbids Women participating in any kinds of sports, only if Islam forbids women from playing any sports, would this conversation go anywhere, if not, there is no need to debate about this. So please quote Quran or Hadith which forbids women form doing sports. Quran 33:33 says "the way they used to expose in the TIMES OF IGNORANCE..". Women used to go for nothing and just to kill time outside, there were no need for a reason to go outside before Islam came., So what is the yardstick of Islam's Need?

Comment: In maqasid shariah, need (hajiyat) is something that will make our life difficult, if not fulfilled. I never said Islam forbids women from participating in sports. Islam forbids women from doing anything that jeopardises their hijab. Hijab isn't just headscarf. Wearing tight clothes is not hijab. Look at the Quranic verse and Hadith in combination. It's clear that women should only go out for their needs. You are a layman, so don't try to interpret Quranic verses. I have already attached Imam Ibn Kathir's comments. Refer to it. Consult a scholar for more.

Comment: You don't seems to be a student of Islam. You are not quoting scriptures or scholars. You shouldn't be answering questions in Islam. Know your limits. Islam is not child's play. Picture you attached is not hijab according to all the four madhabs. Why did you attach it? You are misguiding the questioner.

Comment: >Ibn Kathir (RH) states in his tafseer of this verse that women should not go out for absolutely no reason and there should be a purpose for going out, which is perfectly logical.  His definition is my definition. "women should not go out for ABSOLUTELY NOT REASON" is what he said, and going for a sport is a reason. Isn't sport an education, exercise? I didn;t say head scarf was hijab, and i said shouldn't wear tight dress also.

Comment: what do you mean student of islam? I am a muslim and i read quran and hadith, am i not qualified enough? Then what do the so-called student of islam do? do they create their own quran or study the quran. They do what i do. So stop slandering me for no reason.

Comment: This is what Imam Ibn Kathir exactly said: "Stay in your houses and do not come out without any need, and from amongst the needs which are valid according to Shariah is prayer in the Masjid (even though their houses are better for them), so long as the conditions are fulfilled." Sports is not an education. She could do exercise at home. It's not like she should participate in sports or it will make her life difficult. Participating in sports requires wearing tight clothes. It's problematic in many ways.

Comment: You didn't quote Quran or hadith to make a point. That's a problem. Not everyone who reads Quran and Hadith are students of Islam. You need to learn aqeedah, tafsir, fiqh, Kalam, tasawwuf, to call yourself as student of Islam. If not, you are just a lay Muslim who read Quran and Hadith. That's not a slander